# Reverse rdesktop or VNC overlay image!

Tags: rdesktop, vnc

I've got a central server (**linux** based) and many clients (**Windows XP Embedded**, afaik) in public places around my country. I need to have these clients to connect to the server with a "*reverse*" tunnel, that is to say that I need to control the clients from the server but the connection is initialized by clients.

The requirement is that, during the connection, an overlay image (or something like that, like a modified version of login screen) is displayed. Some stuff like "Work In Progress".

My first idea was to use vncviewer -listen and vnc in reverse mode, but cannot understand how to obfuscate the work I'm doing. Other idea was to use rdesktop in "reverse" mode, but it seems it does not support it.

Using rdekstop reverse seems the nicest solution (I can login back the user was in before connection, the login manager - which I can modified - is displayed), but any hint will be appreciated!

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a VNC reflector. Check the source in here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-reflector/ and you have an howto in http://links.episd.org/DLoads/PDFs/vncreflector-how-to.pdf

Best of luck,
João Miguel Neves

Comment: I'll try out your solution as fast as I can and come back eventually to mark your answer as accepted! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Other then using RDP in terminal services mode, or an SSH or other out of band connection, I've no idea.